# how to show exact content of ng-repeat using ng-click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to show exact content when I click on data from ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="trailSpot in trail.wayPoints">
   <a ng-click="viewState.showSpotDetails = !viewState.showSpotDetails">
      <p>Spot {{$index + 1}}. {{trailSpot.wpName}}</p>
   </a>
   <p >{{trailSpot.wpDescription}}</p>
</div>
```

When I click the first wpName, I want to show wpDescription only about the first wpName on another div. What should I put in that div.

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="viewState.showSpotDetails">
        <div>
            ???
        </div>
</div>
```

Anybody has any tips on what I am trying to do?Thank you!

Comment: div class="panel-body is inside ng-repeat or outside?

Comment: It's outside ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the object to assign the property like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLs8axLj/

JS

```
var app = angular.module('itemsApp',[]);

app.controller('ItemsCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name:'Test 1',details:'Test 1 Details'},
        {name:'Test 2',details:'Test 2 Details'}
    ];

    $scope.showDetails = function(i) {
        $scope.item_details = i.details;
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="itemsApp" ng-controller="ItemsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="showDetails(i)">{{i.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
 {{item_details}}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh!I got it. It's clear! Thanks! I am new to AngularJs. You help me a lot.